# Upload 10 MB file to SQL Database in MVC

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, file-upload, asp.net-ajax, jquery-file-upload

I want to upload file up to 10MB into my SQL Database. Until now I can upload small files like 0,5MB, but my point is to upload file no bigger than 10MB.

Can somebody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UpdateJsionFile(int? id, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        byte[] bytes;
        //decimal fileSize = 100;
        var supportedTypes = new[] { "txt","doc","docx","pdf", "xls", "xlsx" };
        var fileExt = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower().Substring(1);
        using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(file.InputStream))
        {
            bytes = br.ReadBytes(file.ContentLength);
        }

        if(!supportedTypes.Contains(fileExt))
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, error = "File extention is invalid - upload only WORD/PDF/EXCEL/TXT files" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }


        if(file.FileName.Length>50 )
        {
            return Json(new { success = false, error = "File name is too long, max. 50 symbols" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

        //if (file.ContentLength > (fileSize * 1024))
        //{
        //    return Json(new { success = false, error = "File size is too big" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        //}


        using (FileDBEntities db = new FileDBEntities())
        {
            tblFile f = db.tblFiles.Where(p => p.id == id).FirstOrDefault();

            f.Name = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
            f.ContentType = file.ContentType;
            f.Data = bytes;

            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return Json(new { success = true }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

    }
```

like I was saying, this code works perfectley with small files, but if I want to upload a "big" one(from 1 MB), I'm recieving every time message like:

function(){if(a){var t=a.length;(function r(t){v.each(t,function(t,n){var i=v.type(n);i==="function"?(!e.unique||!c.has(n))&&a.push(n):n&&n.length&&i!=="string"&&r(n)})})(arguments),i?o=a.length:n&&(s=t,l(n))}return this}

Comment: I've changed Web.config to <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" /> and it seems to work, but now i have another problem, that my Json in UI doesn't work after upload...

Answer (score 0):

I've changed in Web.config:

```
<system.web>
<compilation debug="true"/>
  <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="10240" />
</system.web>
```

it works, but not really with Json, file was uploaded but in UI i cant see it any more, at the same time a "normal" razor works...